# PDFs showing blank pages in all apps on El Capitan

Tags: mac, finder, macos, pdf, preview

Hey I'm having an issue where if I open PDFs then sometimes the last few pages are just totally blank. Then sometimes it doesn't display any of the pages at all, and sometimes it works fine. I can't seem to find any reason this might be happening, I've tried a few different PDFs and it just seems random. Eventually the PDF does sometimes display properly, but only after a few minute. It happens intermittently on both Preview and Skim, but *doesn't* happen on the spacebar finder preview, which *always* displays it fine.

Here is an example. You can see that the table of contents in the sidebar are also "greyed out".

[image: Preview broken PDF]

Here is the the same PDF in Skim. Showing all but the last few pages as working.

[image: Skim broken PDF]

I've tried restarting and it didn't change anything.

Running El Capitan 10.11.1 (15B42)

Comment: What are your results with Acrobat Reader DC? Are there error messages?